# Why is Perl's floor function off by 1?

Tags: perl, floor

Perl's floor function is giving me unexpected results.

floor(13320) = 13320, but floor(133.20 * 100) = 13319. I'd think both of those would get the same result. Why is this happening?

```
use POSIX;

print floor(133.20);       # 133, as expected
print floor(13320);        # 13320, as expected
print floor(133.20 * 100); # 13319?
```

Comment: `printf("%.20f",133.20*100)` for enlightenment

Comment: 2/10 is a periodic number in binary, just like 1/3 is a periodic number in decimal. As such, 2/10 can't be accurately represented by a floating-point number. (That would require infinite storage.) So instead of `133.20`, you end up with `133.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875`

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)